# Pre-loader con javascript cargado solo una vez

Tags: javascript, html, css

Disculpen amigos lo que pasa es que tengo una pregunta con javascript tengo un pre-loader y quisiera saber como podría hacer para que ese pre-loader aparezca solo una vez, a lo que me refiero es que el usuario al momento de estar navegando por las pestañas no esté apareciendo el pre-loader cada vez que cambias de pestaña, que se cargue solo una vez al ser la primera vez que se abra la página soy nuevo en javascript y no sé de que manera solucionarlo aquí dejo el código

```
<div id="loader"></div>
<div id="content">
    <h1>GIF Pre-Loader</h1>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var loader;
    function loadNow(opacity) {
        if(opacity <= 0) {
            displayContent();
        }
        else {
            loader.style.opacity = opacity;
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                loadNow(opacity - 0.05)
            }, 100);
        }
    }

    function displayContent() {
        loader.style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('content').style.display = 'block';
    }

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        loader = document.getElementById('loader');
        loadNow(1);
    });

</script>
```

Ayuda porfavor

Comment: Las pestañas te mueves por ellas con javascript o con etiquetas <a>?

Comment: con etiquetas <a>

Answer (score 0):

Pongamos que tienes una estructura de ficheros html

```
carpeta
|-index.html
|-pagina1.html
|-pagina2.html
|-pagina3.html
```

Y quieres que se muestre solo en `pagina1.html` una manera de hacerlo sería haciendo un if que cuando estés en la página `pagina1.html` se ejecute. Para lograr eso utilizaremos el `window.location.pathname` que devuelve el directorio actual en el que estas, luego ejecutaremos un substring para eliminar los directorio y retornar solo el nombre del fichero. De esta forma sacaremos el nombre del fichero:

```
var directorio=window.location.pathname;
var fichero=dir.substring(dir.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
if(fichero=="pagina1.html"){
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            loader = document.getElementById('loader');
            loadNow(1);
        });
}
```

Comment: Ya lo probé, pero se queda cargando el pre-loader